# install docker engine without docker desktop on MacOS

Tags: macos, docker

Docker recently upgraded its license that using Docker Desktop is a paid feature.  I don't use Desktop but I do use the built-in Docker Engine.  The `Docker > About` implies they are two separate things:

[image: desktop vs engine]

My question is really two: (1) if I'm not violating licensure by *only actually using* the engine, then don't really need the rest but if not or just for grins' sake then (2) how to install docker engine without docker desktop?

Comment: Any chance you can edit this to show your research? The licensing terms are very clear what use of all products is free and when the licensing wants a payment. https://www.docker.com/legal/docker-subscription-service-agreement/

Comment: If you’re not using docker on macOS please flag this for migration to another site or edit in which platform or community best matches your situation.